# fmt format %H:%M:%S without decimals

Tags: c++, formatting, c++20, c++-chrono, fmt

I am trying to format a `std::chrono::duration` object to the format HH:MM::SS, e.g. 16:42:02 being the hours (16), the minutes (42), and the seconds (2).

the library `fmt` offers useful formatting specifiers for this:

```
using namespace std::chrono;

auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
auto end = start + 4s;
fmt::print("{:%H:%M:%S} \n", end);
```

which unfortuantely prints the seconds in decimals

```
16:58:55.359425076
```

I want to round this to the nearest integer, but cannot figure out where to place the precision specifier (precision 2 merely test-wise):

```
fmt::print("{:.2%H:%M:%S} \n", end);  // error
fmt::print("{:.2f%H:%M:%S} \n", end);  // error 
fmt::print("{:%H:%M:.2%S} \n", end);  // nonsense: 17:07:.202.454873454
```

I am a bit lost staring at the details of the [formatspec](https://fmt.dev/latest/syntax.html#formatspec) for chrono...

A compiler explorer example of the above is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/zGcb6W84Y).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To round to the nearest second, convert your time point to seconds precision using `round<seconds>(tp)`.  Also, `high_resolution_clock` has no portable relationship to the calendar.  You need to use `system_clock` instead.  For gcc, `high_resolution_clock` is a type alias of `system_clock`, so it works by accident. But this will fail to compile using MSVC or LLVM tools.

```
#include <fmt/chrono.h>
#include <fmt/format.h>

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto start = round<seconds>(system_clock::now());
    auto end = start + 4s;
    fmt::print("{:%H:%M:%S} \n", end);
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/qa5cdKPoc)

If you would like other rounding modes you can use `floor` or `ceil` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how well this converts to `<fmt>` but for the Standard C++ `<format>`, you could possibly get whole seconds as your locale's *alternative representation* using the `%OS` specifier.

Or we can use the locale's representation of the whole time, using `%X` or `%EX`.

Certainly, this works on my Debian system (note we pass the "C" locale to `format()`):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main()
{
    using clock = std::chrono::system_clock;

    std::cout << std::format(std::locale::classic(), "{:%X} \n", clock::now());
}
```

Produces (for example):

```
16:42:02
```